# deploy Angular2 application on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy an angular2 application on Firebase. I've followed [this](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/deploying.html) guide but when I type `firebase open` I get an error (see below).

This is the structure of my application

```
\root
    \ app
    \ assets
    \ dev
    \ node_modules
    \ public
    \ src
    \ typings
    index.html
    firebase.json
    gulpfile.js
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    typings.json
```

I've put all the files inside my `app` folder (they're `.js` files, transpiled from `.ts` ones which are inside `dev` folder) inside public folder. I've copied index.html file inside public folder as well.

So now public folder structure is:

```
\public
    \app
       |-> app.component.js
       |-> boot.js
       |-> other .js files
    index.html
```

this is index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular 2 Boilerplate</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>

<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my firebase.json is like this:

```
{
  "firebase": "wetta",
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

The error that google chrome console `shows is: (index):24 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined`

Am I going in the right direction? What is causing this error?

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of the problem is that the script from index.html wants to call

**System.config(...**

but the System object which is defined in

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

wasn't loaded because in your firebase.json you have ignore rule for **/node_modules/** and the system.src.js is not uploaded on Firebase server.

It wouldn't be practical to upload all the stuff from node_modules, because there are way to many files.

I was able to solve the problem with following steps:

- created Angular 2 application with **angular-cli**
- built my application with **ng build** which created **dist** folder with my app
- initialize with **firebase init** . For question "What directory should be the public root?" give answer **dist** .
- **firebase deploy**